# Laravel 6 relations one-to-many with different table names in DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I've got a big problem with relations, unfortunetly I decided to use different names of models and tables in database, so laravel can't match these correctly. 
I have added `protected $table` variable to FuseCollector model, and table name and column name as a 2nd and 3rd atributes in `hasMany()` method in User model, but it still doesn't work. I'm looking for solution for two days and pulling hair out of my head. Please help!

My DB tables:

```
fusecollector_projects: id (key), user_id (foreign key), notes, created_at, updated_at
users: id (key), name, email, email_verified_at, password, remember_token, created_at, updated_at
```

Model FuseCollector (App\FuseCollector.php)

```
namespace App\FuseCollector;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'fusecollector_projects';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'notes'
    ];
     public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Model User (App\User.php)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    public function fuseCollectorProjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\FuseCollector\Project', 'fusecollector_projects', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Controller Project (App\Http\Controllers\FuseController\Project.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\FuseCollector;

use Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateFCProjectRequest;
use App\FuseCollector\Project;
use Auth;
use Session;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
//use App\Http\Requests;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('fusecollector.project.index');
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view('fusecollector.project.create');
    }
    public function store(CreateFCProjectRequest $request) // zapisywanie projektu do bazy
    {
        $project = new Project($request->all());
        Auth::user()->fuseCollectorProjects()->save($project);
        Session::flash('video_saved', 'Film został zapisany');
        return redirect('fusecollector.project.index');
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to use create() method from my simply create form (only 'name' and 'notes'fields) i receive error message:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function fuseCollectorProjects() on null
App\Http\Controllers\FuseCollector\ProjectController::store:26
```

26th line is:

```
Auth::user()->fuseCollectorProjects()->save($project);
```

I know there is some problem with relations, so I tried to check relations in php artisan tinker:

```
>>> $p = new App\FuseCollector\Project
=> App\FuseCollector\Project {#3061}
>>> $p->first()
=> App\FuseCollector\Project {#3068
     id: 1,
     name: "Projekt",
     user_id: 1,
     notes: "aaa",
     created_at: "2020-01-04 23:42:12",
     updated_at: "2020-01-04 23:42:12",
   }
>>> $u = new App\User
=> App\User {#3055}
>>> $u->first()
=> App\User {#3072
     id: 1,
     name: "ForgottenLord",
     email: "xxxk@gmail.com",
     email_verified_at: null,
     created_at: "2020-01-04 01:00:49",
     updated_at: "2020-01-04 01:00:49",
   }
>>> $p->user()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo {#3063}
>>> $u->fuseCollectorProjects()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany {#3070}
```

It shows that there is no relations and I don't know why!

Comment: The `Auth::user()` in your example returns `null` indicating that you're not logged in when the `store(..)` method is called

Comment: omg, it was sooo simple! I forgot that I was logged out.Thans you so much!

Comment: I found 2 another fails: I removed 2nd attribude in `hasMany()`, and correct `return redirect()`.
New problem: why I can't show related projects or user in php artisan tinker?
I know I forget to use `get()` method, but it still doesn't show any reasults:
`>>> $u->fuseCollectorProjects()->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3082
     all: [],`